# flask Welcome to nginx! message when deployed on AWS

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

This is my configuration file:

```
server  {
    listen 80;
    server_name 52.56.87.5;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }
}
```

With `Route53` I enabled both port 80 and port 8080. when I go to my domain `example.com` and listen is @ 80 it shows the message `welcome to Nginx`. While if listen is at 8080 and I go to `example.com:8080` it shows my app. How do I get it to work with just `example.com`?

The `cmod.d` folder is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by replacing the server_name variable with example.com. Previously in fact it did work fine when going directly to 52.56.87.5.